# How to limit memory usage of docker

Tags: docker

I tried to limit the maximum memory docker container can use like:

```
docker run -m --memory=512m
```

And I'm getting

> invalid argument "--memory=512m" for "-m, --memory" flag: invalid size: '--memory=512m'

I couldn't find any examples in the documentation [Docker Doc](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a flag and value with a space between them. You must also specify the image name in your command

```
docker run -m 512m {{IMAGE}}
```